# nesting too deep in JSON... should I switch to XML?

Tags: java, json, exception, nested

I am getting a JSONException complaining about a very deep nesting (more than 30). I know that the value is hardcoded in JSONWriter. 
what best can I do? use another library without this restriction if such thing exists? switch to XML?

**UPDATE:**
I am serializing a labeled tree structure into JSON. So starting with root, each node is nesting its children which in turn nesting theirs...

```
{"type":"n1","links":[{"label":"l1","target":{"type":"n2","links":[{"label":"l2","target":{  ...}}]}}]}
```

I might have to rethink the way I am serializing my object structure.

**UPDATE**: I am using org.json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say which JSON package you are using. It sounds like a defective one (org.json's default one? I almost wish it didn't exist) -- 30 is peanuts, absolutely should not cause problems. If you had thousands I could see why it could lead to problems, but 30 should be no problem.
So consider switching the lib; usually you have many other issues if you hit into simple ones early on.

Comment: it is org.json I will switch to another lib. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may ask yourself if such a deep nesting makes sense at all. Is it really needed? Maybe you could give us an example why you'd need such a deep nesting.